# 'quiver' function in MMA (quiver(x,y,u,v))

Tags: plotting, matlab

How to calculate Quiver using the "***quiver function***" ("Matlab-like")?

> quiver(x,y,u,v) plots vectors as arrows at the coordinates specified
> in each corresponding pair of elements in x and y. The matrices x, y,
> u, and v must all be the same size and contain corresponding position
> and velocity components.

The simple test input looks like (in Matlab):

```
X = rand(21,21); 
Y =rand(21,21); 
DX = rand(21,21); 
DY = rand(21,21);
 
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY)
```

Output:

[image]

Based on @thorimur's suggestion, we can try

```
XX = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
YY = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
DXX = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
DYY = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
points = Transpose[{XX, YY}]; vs = 
 Transpose[{DXX, DYY}]; ListVectorPlot@Transpose[{points, vs}];
```

It does not work.

> Set::shape: Lists
> {{System`VectorPlotsDump`xmin$15383,System`VectorPlotsDump`xmax$15383},{System`VectorPlotsDump`ymin$15383,System`VectorPlotsDump`ymax$15383}}
> and
> {{0.0247279,0.984771},{0.00766939,0.985652},<<7>>,{0.00683188,0.984977},<<11>>}
> are not the same shape.

Comment: Typically in MMA you would have a list of points (pairs of numbers) as opposed to lists `X` and `Y`, but to translate: `points = Transpose[{X, Y}]; vs = Transpose[{DX, DY}]; ListVectorPlot@Transpose[{points, vs}]`

Comment: @thorimur  your solution is not for this case, since X, Y ist matrix not list/vector.

Comment: What is the meaning of a matrix of `X` values, then? Shouldn't it be a list?

Comment: @thorimur "rand(21,21) " for X creates a matrix, not a list.

Comment: Right but...do the dimensions of `X` even matter if we're just going to plot every element in the matrix? Should we not simply take `X = Flatten[X]`? Does `points = Transpose[Flatten/@{X, Y}]; vs = Transpose[Flatten/@{DX, DY}]; ListVectorPlot@Transpose[{points, vs}]` work for you?

Comment: @thorimur  you may see this post again.

Comment: look at my latest comment again...

Comment: Once again, please avoid using random numbers as the sample input, currently even MATLAB users are not able to reproduce the sample output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to mimic MATLAB syntax, you can define quiver as such:

```
quiver[X_, Y_, DX_, DY_, opts___] :=
 Block[{points = Transpose[Flatten /@ {X, Y}]}, 
   ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{points, Transpose[Flatten /@ {DX, DY}]}],
     VectorPoints -> points, opts]] /; 
  AllTrue[{X, Y, DX, DY}, ArrayQ] && Equal @@ Dimensions /@ {X, Y, DX, DY}
```

This lets you pass options to `ListVectorPlot` in the last argument, which is convenient. :) (It also works for arbitrary arrays, including lists and higher-order tensors.)

```
XX = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
YY = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
DXX = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];
DYY = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {21, 21}];

quiver[XX, YY, DXX, DYY]
```

[image: A ListVectorPlot with vectors plotted at random points]
You can make it look even more like MATLAB's version by passing `VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> None` as options:

```
quiver[XX, YY, DXX, DYY, VectorScaling -> Automatic, VectorColorFunction -> None]
```

[image: The same, but with scaling instead of color variation.]

Comment: can we put this function in a default file that we can call this function in other .nb files?

Comment: Yes! but I fear I may have done something wrong looking at it now—the points appear too regularly-spaced. let me troubleshoot...

Comment: @ABCDEMMM ok, now I'm confused—`VectorPoints -> All` should make it plot the actual coordinates, but it's not working. hmmm

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Ok, got it working! looks like `VectorPoints -> All` might not work anymore, which actually seems to be a bug.

Comment: @ABCDEMMM To put the function in a package, check out [this guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/CreateAPackageFile.html), among others!